# Get user from server to server notification of subscription ios

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

I am using sever to server notifications of ios https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_server-to-server_notifications.
It is giving me the notifications but there are no information that to which user this transaction belongs or who paid for it, so am I missing something or there are other ways to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only rely on `original_transaction_id`. It's unique identifier of subscription. In case you have one subscription group it also identifies your user. However you have to implement your own logic by matching your users with `original_transaction_id`s. 
You can also use ready-to-use solution to handle Apple notifications, like [Apphud](https://apphud.com?utm_source=s).

Comment: How should we handle if a user has 2 accounts on our app but have a single Apple ID how will he manage subscriptions for both?

Comment: Every developer decides how to manage this case. One of solution is to assign subscription to logged in account. When user changes account in your app, you assign subscription to that account. So at same time subscription can be applied to one account only.

Comment: How to determine the user from INITIAL_BUY server-sever notification since we can pass user_id matched original_transaction_id after INITIAL_BUY